# Solving $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2\cdot e^x$ with L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Use the L'Hopital rule to solve:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2\cdot e^x$$

I need a quotient of infinities or of zeroes. One way could be this:

$$\frac{e^x}{x^{-2}} = \frac{0}{0}$$

So we apply the L'Hopital rule:

$$\frac{e^x}{-2x^{-3}}$$

Oh, this is not going to work. We'll be applying L'Hopital countless times without luck.

Perhaps this arrangement will do:

$$\frac{x^{2}}{e^{-x}} = \frac{\infty}{0}$$

Nope.

Maybe I could use one of the properties of natural logarithms. Since $e^x = \ln(x)$ I could have

$$\frac{x^2}{\ln(-x)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

Great! Now we can apply the L'Hopital rule:

$$\frac{2x}{\frac{-1}{\ln(-x)}} = \frac{-\infty}{0}$$

Dammit. Well, maybe we can re-arrange this:

$$\frac{2x}{\frac{-1}{\ln(-x)}} = 2x\cdot -\ln(-x)$$

Then,

$$2x\cdot -\ln(-x) = -\infty \cdot -\infty = \infty$$

Apparently this is wrong. The answer should be $0$.

**What was my mistake?**

Comment: Hint : try the substitution $y = -x$ .

Comment: how do you figure that $e^x = ln(x)$ ?

Comment: @Zol I think you can make a generalization of $x^ne^x$ when $x$ goes to negative infinity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The nope should be a yeah! 
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-x} = \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{x} = \infty
$$

Comment: Just so this is clear to the original poster, notice that $x$ is going to _negative_ infinity.

Comment: Do we have to change $x\to -\infty$ to $x \to \infty$? Can't we just keep $e^{-x}$? Because when you evaluate, it will become $e^{--\infty}$ anyway.

Comment: No you do not have to change directions. I just thought that made the limit value a bit easier to understand.

Answer (score 6):

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}x^2\cdot e^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{ e^x}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^xx^2=$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}x^2}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}e^{-x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x}{-e^{-x}}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}-2e^xx=$$
$$-2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^xx\right)=$$
$$-2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{x}{e^{-x}}\right)=$$
$$-2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}x}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}e^{-x}}\right)=$$
$$-2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{-e^{-x}}\right)=$$
$$-2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}-e^x\right)=$$
$$2\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x\right)=$$
$$2\left(\exp\left(\lim_{x\to -\infty}x\right)\right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$ln(e^x) = x$, not $ln(x) =e^x$
And indeed, the limit is $0$.

You have $x^2 e^x = \frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}$,  and, by applying l'Hôpital's rule twice, you get :

$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} x^2 e^x = \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} \frac{2x} {-e^{-x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} \frac{2} {e^{-x}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} 2 e^x = 0 $